# Help with reasons for rebellions against my oligarchic/Philosopher kings inspired empire

Tags: creative-writing, world-building

The government of this (fantasy) world is made up of a small group, randomly chosen at birth and representing maybe 0.5% of the population. The group are tutored in their homes with their families for 5 years, then retain some contact whilst in specialist academies until the age of 18 when they assume full voting rights as part of the Assembly, and travel to various government buildings/courts to vote in the affairs of the state.
I am aware of the problems any empire may have (religious differences, clashing cultural identities etc.), but I want opinions on what other reasons groups might rebel against *this* empire. For example, the one reason I already have is that it is slow (takes 18 years) to add representatives of other cultures. It also occurs to me that gerontocratic tribes may have trouble excepting 18 year olds as their representatives, as to start with the empire likes to work with representatives of the old structure.

Comment: Hi BlandedGear! Welcome to Writing.SE! Please take a look at our [tour] and [help] pages, you might find them useful. I am afraid your question is off topic for us: we can help you with *how* to write: technique, language use, tropes, etc., but we cannot help you come up with *what* to write. That's where your imagination as a writer must come in.

Comment: Hi Blanded Gear, this question would probably be fine on Worldbuilding SE. I will ask if the mods can migrate it.

Comment: 0.5% - is this the total number of children selected from broad population, or just a few children are getting selected from families representing 0.5% of population?

Comment: 0.5% from the broader population, I would also add that it is 0.5% of each region in order to avoid 'flukey' lacks of representatives of earlier nationalities.

Comment: This question looks on topic for worldbuilding.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Definitely looks like a better Stack Exchange for this question, I did not realise that a separate worldbuilding stack exchange existed. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hi and welcome.  As written this question would be too broad for Worldbuilding, but if you can narrow it down you're welcome to ask there.  See [Worldbuilding's help](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more about scope.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The big reason for rebellion is simple, the leaders are not delivering what they are supposed to: safety, prosperity (whatever that means to your culture, it may be as little as Food and water, or if they are more sophisticated, high tech, health, education, etc).

It doesn't make a difference WHY they don't deliver or if it is due to circumstances beyond their control. There is an apocryphal saying, "No country is more than three meals away from revolution". (Or "from anarchy", or "from barbarism", whatever strikes your fancy).

Empire after empire in history collapsed due to simple droughts or crop failures leading to famine, Ireland was pretty much destroyed by the potato famine.

Your second cause of failure is when hard times come, the people in power use their power to ensure they remain comfortable while their people suffer. Same thing here, nobody gives a crap about "philosophy" and "intelligence" and "education" (and I am PhD with five college degrees saying that) when their children are starving. They say screw your laws, I'm going to take a gun (or a knife or a sharp stick if that's all they can have (and everybody can have a sharp stick!)) and go ***take*** some damn food before we die.

When that collides with your police force, the populace will overwhelm them. But your police force is starving too, so ...

As long as people are reasonably surviving and have the basics they have come to expect in terms of food, shelter, health care, jobs (at some given level of effort), entertainment (much more important than most think), and lack of oppression (in taxes, physical harm, taking of property, being jailed or punished), they are unlikely to revolt. When they start losing what they have become accustomed to, that is when resentment sets in, and eventually revolution.

But things have to get pretty bad to make most humans choose to risk actual death. They will try many less consequential things first, and those must fail.

#### Revolutions are about saving your life.

That sounds paradoxical, but they are seldom about ideals or principles. People risk death for a better life, seldom for an idea. Revolutions are about fighting intolerable oppressions, taking of property, killings, rape, or about hunger, shelter, etc. Revolutions are about not being slaved, or not starving or dying of thirst, or not becoming homeless or you or your family or children dying of curable diseases.

Comment: Umm... sorry if I wasn't clear about this in the question, but this is about rebellions motivated by this particular Empire, not all of Empires in all of time. This said, your explanation of many causes of general revolutions was commendably clear.

Comment: @BlandedGear I don't know enough of your story, but your revolution will be caused for the same reason as virtually every other revolution in history. It won't be pique at the age of the rulers, or that they are elite, or that it isn't a Democracy. It will be about ***their*** lives being ruined or full of hardship and grief or state-endorsed robbery, that is why your citizens will risk their own lives, spouses and children in war, because their lives have grown intolerable. There is nothing special in your setup that creates that sort of misery. But the actions of your leaders could do that.

Comment: My story is not centring on the revolution-_why would someone write a story who didn't think of such a big plot point?_-but instead involves revolutions in the environment to reflect the lot of a long lived empire and to stretch resources thinner. One of the uses for historical revolutions is that I want excerpts of the lessons of the rulers, to make the universe fell more lived in, as well as help give exposition on the empire as something long-lived that has gone through hardships and struggles. This may be more of a 'think out of the box question' than a 'help me, human wikipedia' question.

Comment: @BlandedGear You asked for help with reasons for rebellions! It is in the title. You provide an unremarkable ruling class (many monarchies have been worse and crowned kings as toddlers), and implausible reasons for rebellion (nobody dies for "diversity" or for your other reasons), so I provided you with actual historical reasons for revolution, rebellion, whatever you wish to call it. Absent these hardships, if your philosophy majors command an army or police to enforce their rulings, then dissent is not big enough to produce a real rebellion. Historical or otherwise. Good luck.